# A Shortcut Symbol for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

What is this symbol on the keyboard?

[image: Hide]

Answer (score 1):

`Shift + Esc` is keyboard shortcut for it.

> The tool window you are going to hide is currently active, press `Shift + Escape`.